# For what $a>0$ does this integral converge? $\int_{1}^{\infty} {\frac{x^a(\sin x+2)}{x^{2a}\ln(a)}}$

Tags: calculus

> For what $a>0$ does this integral converge?
>   $$\int_{1}^{\infty} {\dfrac{x^a(\sin x+2)}{x^{2a}\ln(a)}}$$

So I said:

> $\left|\dfrac{x^a(\sin x+2)}{x^{2a}\ln(a)} \right| \leq \left| \dfrac{3x^a}{x^{2a}\ln(a)} \right| = \left|\dfrac{3}{x^a \ln(a)} \right|$, and we know that
>   $$
> \int_{1}^{\infty} {\frac{3}{x^a \ln(a)}} = \frac{3}{\ln(a)} \int_{1}^{\infty} {\frac{1}{x^a}}
> $$
>   is convergent for $a > 1$ and thus our original integral.

But my professor said that this convergence test is only for non-negative integrals, but if not like this, then how do we do it?

Comment: That method works for integrals where the integrand doesn't change sign (not just non-negative). It will also help to bound from below.

Comment: You are missing $dx$.

Comment: davin, so what do we do when our integral is not positive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can ignore $\ln(a)$ in the denominator, since it's well defined for all $a>0$ and is constant, therefore doesn't affect convergence. Then in our domain,

$$
\frac 1 {x^a} \leq \frac{x^a(\sin x+2)}{x^{2a}} \leq \frac 3 {x^a}
$$

Which proves, like you concluded, that the integral is convergent for $a>1$ **and** that the integral is divergent for $a\leq1$.

Regarding the absolute value technique, it works for non-negative functions. But also for non-positive functions. If $f(x)\leq 0$ then $\int f(x) = -\int -f(x)$ where $-f(x)\geq 0$. What I've written is essentially the same thing, since as you can see, the function is bounded from below by a positive function, so you can put absolute value signs everywhere if you like.

Comment: Much thanks, appreciated.

Comment: @TheNotMe, a pleasure.